# Is it possible to seed users into the DB with the Clearance gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clearance

I'm working on a Ruby-on-Rails project using the Clearance gem for authentication. Is there a way to use the seeds.rb file to seed users into my database, or do I have to manually create users on the sign-in page? It looks like the user table is structured with an encrypted-password attribute so I'm not sure how to go about seeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation does not say you have to do anything fancy.

```
def create_user(email)
  User.create!(
    email:  email,
    password: "password1234"
  )
end

#fake  users
1...50.times do |i|
  create_user("person_#{i}@test#{i}.io")
end
```

#### in console

```
  User.last
  => <User id: 50, created_at: "2018-05-31 18:51:57", updated_at: "2018-05-31 18:51:57", email: "person_49@test49.io", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$JBWpdFocyd1TTBy5W30uYuWaD5nTo1TPErtQpt2nNZO...", confirmation_token: nil, remember_token: "cfaf107ea30d3303bb991f61973368b2a1fd44c7">
```